# fault incrementing a parameter in a loop

Tags: c++

I have a problem here where the loop is incrementing currentList and I can't relate what would be the problem. I don't know If I am missing something or I should clean the and rebuild?

```
int currentList = 0;
bool gatesBool[2][7];
bool currentGateList[];

EV << "CurrentList 1 is " << currentList << endl;

for (int x=0; x!=7; x++)
{

    EV << "CurrentList 2 is " << currentList << endl;

    if ( gatesBool[currentList][x] == true)
    {
        currentGateList[x] = true; 
        EV << "CurrentList 3 is " << currentList << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        currentGateList[x] = false; 
        EV << "CurrentList 3 is " << currentList << endl;
    }
};
```

> CurrentList 1 is 0
>   CurrentList 2 is 0
>   CurrentList 3 is 1
>   CurrentList 2 is 1
>   CurrentList 3 is 1
>   CurrentList 2 is 1
>   CurrentList 3 is 1
>   CurrentList 2 is 1
>   CurrentList 3 is 1
>   CurrentList 2 is 1
>   CurrentList 3 is 1
>   CurrentList 2 is 1
>   CurrentList 3 is 1
>   CurrentList 2 is 1
>   CurrentList 3 is 1

Comment: What do you think the declaration `bool currentGateList[];` means ?

Comment: vector of type bool of any size that will be defined in the code?

Comment: No, it's not a vector, just a C style array, and it needs to be large enough to handle the range of x values you are using (7 in this case).

Comment: you are correct setting it to 7 solved the problem